# Custom pipe must be async

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-pipe

I have this pipe that's already used throughout the app and it's not to be updated with some async logic. So, the `PipeTransform` interface expects a synchronous `transform` method in my component.

The only option that worked for me is adding a `| async` pipe in all my views. Not the best as my custom pipe would always need that downstream `async` pipe.

Is there a way to create custom `PipeTransform` implementations whose `transform` method can handle async code?

I'm trying to get something like the following to work, with no success so far:

```
transform(value, args) {
    const source$ = of("abc");
    const response = await source$.pipe(first()).toPromise();
    return response;
  }
```

Comment: Is 'Impure Pipe' what you want? https://angular.io/guide/pipes#the-impure-asyncpipe

Comment: Thanks. Interesting and I didn't know about impure pipes. Reading the doc makes it unfit for my need (too many instances in my case). I'll stick to returning an observable and adding a | async pipe for now.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @wannadream, I could add the 'pure: false' property to my pipe decorator.

It's unfit in my case as there would be 200+ pipes in the entire app. Impure implies that:

- there is one instance of an impure pipe created every time it is used.
- impure pipes' `transform()` method is called upon every possible event.

I'll rename `myPipe` into `myPipe$` and use it in the following way:

```
[data] = 'aValue | myPipe$ | async"
```